# how to custom geodjango admin

Tags: geodjango, model, administration

Here is what I do in django:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    pass


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

But with geodjango I have this:

> admin.site.register(MyModel, admin.OSMGeoAdmin)

So I to create my MyModelAdmin class with geodjango?
I want to add a **search_fields**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer it's nearly the same as a normal django admin.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Juste replace admin.ModelAdmin by admin.OSMGeoAdmin

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Django leaflet](https://django-leaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I found this as very interactive. For using this you simply add 
`pip install django-leaflet` at first. And then inside admin.py add this code .

```
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin
admin.site.register(MyModel, BoundaryAdmin)
```

Also you can setup default setting. For this add following code at the end of your setting.py file,

```
# leaflet Module
LEAFLET_CONFIG = {
    'DEFAULT_CENTER': (28.2521, 83.9774), //default center of your map
    'DEFAULT_ZOOM': 18, // default zoom level
    'MIN_ZOOM': 3,
    'MAX_ZOOM': 20,
    'SCALE': 'both',
    'ATTRIBUTION_PRIFIX': 'tekson', //attribution of your map
    'RESET_VIEW': False,
        'TILES': [('OpenStreetMap', 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          'attribution': '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        }),
        ('Drak Map', 'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
            'attribution': '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
            'subdomains': 'abcd',
            'maxZoom': 19
        })],
    }
```